# Eqaution solving & checking program!

Tags: equation-solving

Slove the eqaution 2x^2+5x+1=0 in real number range.

Then, by putting it in the equation, check if that is correct.

(Use NSlove, Chop, and substitution)

I want a code which uses above three operations... help me !

Answer (score 1):

Do you need something like this?

```
eq = 2*z^2 + 5*z + 1;
sol = NSolve[2*x^2 + 5*x + 1 == 0, x, Reals] (*two real solutions*);
eq /. {z -> x /. sol[[1]]} // Chop
eq /. {z -> x /. sol[[2]]} // Chop
```

Comment: hi, I think you can just use `Solve` for this one. No need to use `NSolve`. You could always apply `N` at end to the result to convert exact numbers to machine numbers. It should be more accurate this way.

Comment: sure, but the post asked that NSolve be used

Answer (score 1):

```
eqn = 2 x^2 + 5 x + 1 == 0;
```

The exact solution is

```
sol = Solve[eqn, x, Reals]

(* {{x -> 1/4 (-5 - Sqrt[17])}, {x -> 1/4 (-5 + Sqrt[17])}} *)
```

Verifying that both solutions are valid

```
eqn /. sol

(* {True, True} *)
```

However, for this particular equation the roots are real and it is not necessary to restrict the domain to get **identical** ([`SameQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameQ.html)) results.

```
sol === Solve[eqn, x]

(* True *)
```

For approximate numeric results

```
(soln = NSolve[eqn, x, Reals]) // InputForm

(* {{x -> -2.280776406404415}, 
 {x -> -0.21922359359558485}} *)
```

Note that these are machine numbers with no known precision. The numeric results are consistent with the exact results.

```
soln === (sol // N)

(* True *)
```

However, the verification of the numeric results fails due to a precision issue.

```
eqn /. soln

(* {False, False} *)
```

You can use [`Chop`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html) to verify that the LHS of the equation evaluates to approximately zero.

```
eqn[[1]] /. soln // Chop

(* {0, 0} *)
```

Alternatively, specifying a [`WorkingPrecision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html) will resolve this as the equation's [`Equal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html) test is then done to the precision of the solution.

```
(soln2 = NSolve[eqn, x, Reals, WorkingPrecision -> 10]) // InputForm

(* {{x -> -2.2807764064044149243670744\
9087407439947`10.}, 
 {x -> -0.2192235935955848535883205\
840946175158`10.}} *)
```

Note that the above result indicates that the values have a known precision of `10.` digits consistent with the specified `WorkingPrecision`. The result of the equation's `Equal` test is then

```
eqn /. soln2

(* {True, True} *)
```